# What's the C++ version of Guid.NewGuid()?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, guid

I need to create a `GUID` in an unmanaged windows C++ project.  I'm used to C#, where I'd use `Guid.NewGuid()`.  What's the (unmanaged windows) C++ version?

Comment: C++ doesn't define one. You have to rely on third party libraries or platform-specific OS-provided APIs

Comment: you may want to look at Boost UUID https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I think [`CoCreateGuid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688568%28VS.85%29.aspx) is what you're after.  Example:

```
GUID gidReference;
HRESULT hCreateGuid = CoCreateGuid( &gidReference );
```

Comment: It calls UuidCreate() internally anyway.

Comment: @sharptooth: That's only half the truth. While `CoCreateGuid` does call `UuidCreate`, it provides stronger guarantees with respect to uniqueness. [CoCreateGuid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688568.aspx): *"Use **CoCreateGuid** when you need an absolutely unique number that you will use as a persistent identifier in a distributed environment."*

Comment: Does it need a prior call to CoInitialize()?

Comment: @sharptooth It makes sense when you look from the documentation perspective. The sentence needs a subject, and the editor provided name of the function on the current page. That does not necessarily mean `CoCreateGuid` is doing more than `UuidCreate`.

Answer (score 45):

[UuidCreate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379205(VS.85).aspx) in Win32 API has exactly the same effect. However you need to pass an address of the variable that will receive the generated value:

```
UUID newId;
UuidCreate( &newId );
```

I believe Guid.NewGuid() simply maps onto it inside the .NET runtime.

Comment: That makes a UUID structure, not a GUID structure.

Comment: They're the same, simply different typedef names!

Comment: Yes, but GUIDs only claim to be Globally unique; UUIDs by contract claim to have Universal uniqueness! So if you ever want your code to run on more than one planet, then clearly you should use the latter! (Unfortunately, even the latter may prove to be insufficient if/when quantum computing catches on and the many-universes interpretation turns out to be true...)

Comment: This is not the case. [Guid.NewGuid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) calls [CoCreateGuid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms688568.aspx) (which in turn does call UuidCreate, potentially more than once). The difference is, that CoCreateGuid provides stronger guarantees with respect to uniqueness, so the difference is important.

Comment: @IInspectable Sounds good. Why won't you add another answer explaining all the subtleties?

Comment: @BrendanMcK, and how about multiverse?

Comment: Since separate universes within the multiverse can't communicate with one another (otherwise they'd be considered to be the same universe), UUIDs only need to be unique within any given universe. It's acceptable to use the same UUID value in different universes since they can't collide.

Comment: @IInspectable  so... wait... globally unique is more unique than universally unique? 

Answer (score 18):

Here's a snippet of code to get the resulting string value of the generated GUID:

```
// For UUID
#include <Rpc.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Rpcrt4.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Create a new uuid
    UUID uuid;
    RPC_STATUS ret_val = ::UuidCreate(&uuid);

    if (ret_val == RPC_S_OK)
    {
        // convert UUID to LPWSTR
        WCHAR* wszUuid = NULL;
        ::UuidToStringW(&uuid, (RPC_WSTR*)&wszUuid);
        if (wszUuid != NULL)
        {
            //TODO: do something with wszUuid

            // free up the allocated string
            ::RpcStringFreeW((RPC_WSTR*)&wszUuid);
            wszUuid = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            //TODO: uh oh, couldn't convert the GUID to string (a result of not enough free memory)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //TODO: uh oh, couldn't create the GUID, handle this however you need to
    }

    return 0;
}
```

API reference:

- [UuidCreate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379205.aspx)
- [UuidToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379352.aspx)
- [RpcStringFree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378483.aspx)

Answer (score 11):

The documentation for [Guid.NewGuid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) points out, how it is implemented:

> This is a convenient **static** method that you can call to get a new [Guid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx). The method wraps a call to the Windows [CoCreateGuid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms688568.aspx) function.

So the native equivalent to `Guid.NewGuid()` is `CoCreateGuid()`.

---

[CoCreateGuid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms688568.aspx) calls [UuidCreate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379205.aspx), to generate a GUID. Both API calls are slightly different, though: While `UuidCreate` returns a UUID, that is guaranteed to be unique to the computer that created it, `CoCreateGuid` produces a GUID that is absolutely unique.

If you need to decide, which API to use, here are the relevant sections from the documentation.

[UuidCreate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379205.aspx):

> For security reasons, it is often desirable to keep ethernet addresses on networks from becoming available outside a company or organization. The **UuidCreate** function generates a [**UUID**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379358.aspx) that cannot be traced to the ethernet address of the computer on which it was generated. It also cannot be associated with other **UUIDs** created on the same computer.

[CoCreateGuid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms688568.aspx):

> The **CoCreateGuid** function calls the RPC function [**UuidCreate**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379205.aspx), which creates a GUID, a globally unique 128-bit integer. Use **CoCreateGuid** when you need an absolutely unique number that you will use as a persistent identifier in a distributed environment.

Answer (score 8):

To generate a new guid in windows and get the resulting value as a string.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    GUID guid;
    CoCreateGuid(&guid);

    std::ostringstream os;
    os << std::hex << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0') << guid.Data1;
    os << '-';
    os << std::hex << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << guid.Data2;
    os << '-';
    os << std::hex << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << guid.Data3;
    os << '-';
    os << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<short>(guid.Data4[0]);
    os << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<short>(guid.Data4[1]);
    os << '-';
    os << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<short>(guid.Data4[2]);
    os << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<short>(guid.Data4[3]);
    os << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<short>(guid.Data4[4]);
    os << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<short>(guid.Data4[5]);
    os << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<short>(guid.Data4[6]);
    os << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<short>(guid.Data4[7]);

    std::string s(os.str());
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `sprintf_s` for the string conversion

```
GUID guid;
CoCreateGuid(&guid);
char guidStr[37];
sprintf_s(
    guidStr,
    "%08lX-%04hX-%04hX-%02hhX%02hhX-%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX",
    guid.Data1, guid.Data2, guid.Data3,
    guid.Data4[0], guid.Data4[1], guid.Data4[2], guid.Data4[3],
    guid.Data4[4], guid.Data4[5], guid.Data4[6], guid.Data4[7]);
std::string s(guidStr);
```

Answer (score 3):

To get in guid in std::string on Windows

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <array>

std::string getGUID()
{
    std::string result{};
    GUID guid;

    if (S_OK == CoCreateGuid(&guid))
    {
        std::array<char, 36> buffer{};   //32 characters of guid + 4 '-' in-between

        snprintf(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), "{%08x-%04x-%04x-%02x%02x-%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x}",
                guid.Data1, guid.Data2, guid.Data3, guid.Data4[0], guid.Data4[1], guid.Data4[2], guid.Data4[3], guid.Data4[4], guid.Data4[5], guid.Data4[6], guid.Data4[7]);
        result = std::string(buffer.data());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why not string_view? Or better yet, why not return the std::array? I do not see the reason why you need to allocate std::string. Just my opinion.

Comment: In addition, there is StringFromGUID2.

Answer (score 1):

In the new WinRT api you can use `winrt::Windows::Foundation::GuidHelper::CreateNewGuid()` which returns a struct of `winrt::guid` type. You can later pass it to `winrt::to_hstring` to get struct of `winrt::hstring` type, then pass it to `winrt::to_string` to get `std::string` type.